# How to create certain number of threads dynamically and assign method when any of the thread is completed in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a scenario in which I need to create  number of threads dynamically based on the configurable variable.I can only start that number of thread at a time and as soon as one of the thread is completed,I need to assign a method in same thread as in queue.

Can any one help me to resolve the above scenario with an example.

I have been researching  for a week but not able to get the concrete solution.

Comment: What do you mean with "assign a method"?

Comment: What do you mean? What actual problem are you trying to solve? There are Tasks which you can chain together, you can use `await` or you could use an [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) or a combination of TransformBlock, ActionBlock with a MaximumDegreeOfParallelization set to a certain upper limit. .NET has abstractions that can cover complex scenarios without resorting to raw threads

Comment: I have method suppose A() will write data from one database to another.And method A will run in foreach loop(count 10 suppose) which might take lot of time.So I want to create 5 threads which will assing 5 task to run method A() and once one of the 5 threads complete it should take other task.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this, but which is best depends on your specific problem.

However, let's assume that you have a collection of items that you want to do some work on, with a separate thread processing each item - up to a maximum number of simultaneous threads that you specify.

One very simple way to do that is to use Plinq via `AsParallel()` and `WithDegreeOfParallelism()`, as the following console application demonstrates:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int maxThreads = 4;
            var workItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
            var parallelWorkItems = workItems.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(maxThreads);

            parallelWorkItems.ForAll(worker);
        }

        static void worker(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Worker {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} is processing {value}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate work.
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this and inspect the output, you'll see that multiple threads are processing the work items, but the maximum number of threads is limited to the specified value.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at thread pooling. See this link for more information [Threadpooling in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx). You will most likely have to work with the callbacks to accomplish your task to call a method as soon as work in one thread was done

Comment: No need to work with a ThreadPool directly, Tasks support continuations since 4.0 and `await` makes this even easier in 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a smarter solution for you using `async/await`, depending on what you are trying to achieve. But since you explicitly ask about threads, here is a short class that does what you want:

```
public class MutliThreadWorker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    private readonly List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();
    private bool _disposed;

    private void ThreadFunc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action action;
            while (!_actions.TryDequeue(out action)) Thread.Sleep(100);
            action();
        }
    }
    public MutliThreadWorker(int numberOfThreads)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
            _threads.Add(t);
            t.Start();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _disposed = true;
        foreach (Thread t in _threads)
            t.Abort();
        if (disposing)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    public void Enqueue(Action action)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("MultiThreadWorker");
        _actions.Enqueue(action);
    }

}
```

This class starts the required number of threads when instantiated as this:

```
int requiredThreadCount = 16; // your configured value
MultiThreadWorker mtw = new MultiThreadWorker(requiredThreadCount);
```

It then uses a [ConcurrentQueue<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to keep track of the tasks to do. You can add methods to the queue via

```
mtw.Enqueue(() => DoThisTask());
```

I made it `IDisposable` to make sure the treads are stopped in the end. *Of course this would need a little improvemnt since aborting threads like this is not the best practice.*

The `ThreadFunc` itself checks repeatedly if there are queued actions and executes them. This could also be improved a little by patterns using [Monitor.Pulse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) and [Monitor.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79fkfcw1.aspx) etc.

And as I said, `async/await` may lead to better solutions, but you asked for threads explicitly.